# The "P2" parameter is missing a value (rdlc 2013)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, reporting, rdlc, report-viewer2012

I have 2 questions:

1) I have a parameter of "P2" which is assigned to the text-box but I don't know it is necessary define a datatype for the parameter in Expression or not? If yes, how to get that

2) When I run the reports to make a query .Report gives me an error `Parameter P2 is missing a value`. 
No hidden

Thanks inadvance

```
private void RbtnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)       
{
    ModelRealEstate.DB_RealEstateEntities objdb = new ModelRealEstate.DB_RealEstateEntities();

    var rows = objdb.Tbl_Property
        .Where(x => x.Adress.Contains(mtxbxRprt.Text))
        .ToList();

    reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = ("Report1.rdlc");

    reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(
        new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter(
            "P2", mtxbxRprt.Text));

    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(
        new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource(
            "DataSet1", rows));

    reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
```

Comment: could it be a matter of case sensitivity? For a string compare it matters. p2 is different than P2.

Comment: Thanks, but I've check it now both are capital P2.

Comment: I don't know the solution, but one other suggestion I would like to make is to try by replacing "mtxbxRprt.Text" with some hard coded value that you know would work on the line "new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("P2", mtxbxRprt.Text)". Doing so might help to narrow down the problem area.

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler can you suggest some code for replacing? I am not professional programmer actually.

Comment: We all were a beginner at some point and are always a learner, right? :) Anyways, did you give my earlier suggestion a try? If you did, did you get the same error? If not could you give it a try and tell me what the outcome is?

Comment: you're right...thanks
No I didn't try it due to I do not know what is roll of this code to replace it with other code in fact. 
But I know the outcome. Outcome should be a text( word) like ABC as an dress which is out from Property table.

Comment: The purpose of my earlier suggestion is to check whether it is an issue due to empty string which may be coming from mtxbxRprt.Text. It's a minor change and takes less than a minute. Check this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tclrfG

Comment: I've tried to search by meaning of HARD CODED..
 as you said I've replaced it, noting happened, the same Error.

    reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("P2", "ABC"));

I think I should change some thing in Expression ...

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms252146%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) `SetParameters` needs an `IEnumerable` that contains a list of the report parameter properties.

So you can change your code in:

```
ReportParameter p2 = new ReportParameter("P2", mtxbxRprt.Text);
reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] {p2});
```

Comment: `ReportParameter p2 = new ReportParameter("P2", TXTABC.Text);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { p2 });`

It's give me  Error by Red under-line for esch _ReportParameter _

Comment: I think it is only a problem of Namespaces: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx